# Worklight app: huge amount of requests to server after authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I'm using Worklight Adapter based authentication for m y app. After success response from server about the good passing the authentication test, the application starts to send the request to server over and over.

Logs from server says, that user is login and logout in the loop.

```
{
    "message": "invoke logout request [project ProjectName]",
    "sourceClass": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "sourceMethodName": "info",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 19,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "server": {
      "ip": "--"
    },
    "timestamp": "---"
  }
  {
    "message": "Setting active user [project ProjectName]",
    "sourceClass": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "sourceMethodName": "info",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 19,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "server": {
      "ip": "--"
    },
    "timestamp": "---"
  }
  {
    "message": "invoke logout request [project ProjectName]",
    "sourceClass": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "sourceMethodName": "info",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 21,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "server": {
      "ip": "--"
    },
    "timestamp": "---"
  }
  {
    "message": "Setting active user [project ProjectName]",
    "sourceClass": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "sourceMethodName": "info",
    "level": "INFO",
    "source": "server",
    "threadId": 21,
    "loggerName": "com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation",
    "server": {
      "ip": "--"
    },
    "timestamp": "---"
  }
```

This change of the source code helps to avoid this activity. (Deleting the challengeHandler.submitSuccess() calling)

[image: handleChallenge method declaration]

But in this way, callback function from challendeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication and WL.Client.logout are not called.

[image: Login method declaration. Show the callback function]

All activities are showed in the logs package.

[image: Client logs of the authorization process]

Please help me to release this problem.

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the existing authentication samples and compared it with yours?

Comment: We need more code form your application to see where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking Wl.Client.login("realmname") before submit user credentials helped me.